# std::regex_search vs std::regex_match

Tags: c++, regex, performance, match

I have tested `(@{[^{}]*})*` to match `@{whatever}` and it is correct (https://regex101.com/).
So, in spite of portability nightmare for regular expressions, I finally built the proper std::regex with:

```
const char *re_str = "@\\{[^\\{\\}]*\\}"; // @{[^{}]*} with curly braces escaped.
```

Escapes could be simplified using `R"()"` but that's not the question. As I said, the regex works. Here a simple snippet example which extracts the pattern using `regex_search` through iteration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main () {
  std::string str = "Bye @{foo} ! hi @{bar} !";
  std::smatch matches;
  std::string::const_iterator it( str.cbegin() );

  const char *re_str = "@\\{[^\\{\\}]*\\}"; // @{[^{}]*} with curly braces escaped
  // or: const char *re_str = R"(@\{[^\{\}]*\})";

  try {
    std::regex re(re_str);
    while (std::regex_search(it, str.cend(), matches, re)) {
      std::cout << matches[0] << std::endl;
      it = matches.suffix().first;
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ regex_search.cc && ./a.out
@{foo}
@{bar}
```

it works.

Well, I'm wondering if there is any better approach (performance pov).
So, I tried with `std::regex_match` instead of iterating on `std::regex_search`.
I used a capture group for that, just enclosing previous regular expression within `()*`:

```
const char *re_str = "(@\\{[^\\{\\}]*\\})*"; // (@{[^{}]*})* with curly braces escaped.
```

This is the source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main () {
  std::string str = "Bye @{foo} ! hi @{bar} !";
  std::smatch matches;
  std::string::const_iterator it( str.cbegin() );

  const char *re_str = "(@\\{[^\\{\\}]*\\})*"; // (@{[^{}]*})* with curly braces escaped.

  try {
    std::regex re(re_str);
    if (std::regex_match(str, matches, re)) {
      for (int k=0; k<matches.size(); k++) std::cout << "[" << k << "]: " << matches.str(k) << std::endl;
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
g++ regex_match.cc && ./a.out
```

Its output is empty !!!

I imagine, that's not the way to use `std::regex_match` although it is supposed to extract matches for captured group.
Perhaps the regex this time is invalid (I don't know because, as I said, it is a portability nightmare).

So,

1. is using `regex_search` enough and worths the performance concern ?
2. Is `regex_match` better algorithm or is it equivalent ?
3. What's wrong with my source for `regex_match` ?

BRs, thank you in advance

Comment: for `regex_match` your regex has to match the entire input string, your regex doesn't match the whole string: https://regex101.com/r/4HzmeB/1

Comment: I didn't put initial ^ and final $, so it should match, right?

Comment: No, `regex_match` matches the whole string

Comment: Ok Alan, that's the thing. So, regex_match was misunderstood by me and we should iterate as @MilesBudnek says.

Answer (score 1):

- `std::regex_search` searches for the pattern anywhere in the input string.
- `std::regex_match` checks if the pattern matches the *entire* input string.

Your pattern does not match your entire string, so `std::regex_match` will not  find a match.  You would need something like `.*?(@{[^{}]*}).*?(@{[^{}]*}).*` if you wanted to match the entire string and extract the `@{foo}` and `@{bar}` portions.

If you want to be able to easily find an arbitrary number of matches for a pattern in your string, take a look at [`std::regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).  For example, the following would find all instances of words surrounded by `@{}` and save them to a `std::vector`:

```
auto find_all(const std::string& string, const std::regex& pattern)
{
    std::vector<std::smatch> matches;
    std::sregex_iterator begin{s.begin(), s.end(), pattern};
    std::sregex_iterator end;

    std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(matches));
    return matches;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/270201a095e7d526)

Note: Remember that `std::match_results` hold iterators into the searched string, so make sure not to use it after the string's lifetime ends.

Comment: Yes, same thing here. The foo/bar was just an example. The string could have any arbitrary amount of @{xx} patterns.

Comment: @eramos For that I would use [`std::regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator).  It's designed for finding and iterating through all of the matches for a regex in a string.